# Vertically aligning spans next to an image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build an `<ul>` entry structure like the one depicted here:

[image]

As pointed in the picture, the red box is a `<li>.`

Also, if I dynamically remove the bottom `<span>` that's situated next to the image, I'd like the top `<span>` to be vertically centered (next to the image, of course).

I've had my attempts turning everything into block and playing with widths and heights but I wonder if there's a 'cleaner' version out there.

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:**

### [My current code:](http://jsfiddle.net/PUsBR/)

#### HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <span><img src="http://ctelab.berkeley.edu/Images/image%202_use.jpg" /></span>
    <span>Text1</span>
    <span>Text2</span>
    <span>Text3</span>
</li>
</ul>​
```

#### CSS:

```
li{
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 20px;
}
span:first-child{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px; 
    height: 120px; /* width and height of the image*/
    vertical-align: middle;
}
span{
    border: 1px dashed green;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

As much as I know only TD element support vertical alignment nothing else. If you want vertical alignment (positioning SPAN in the middle of LI) I suggest you two way:

Do it with JS or convert your LI to a TD.